# Use one Grep to run another

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep

So, here's my use case. I have a folder with around a thousand files in it (logs). First, I 'cd' to the folder, then I use one grep to determine the list of logs that are of a specific type, like so:

```
grep -li 'search string' *
```

This dumps out a list of all the files that contain my search string. This subset are the ones I need to work with. Next what I need to do is pull lines of information from each of those files. Namely, they have a version number preceded by a specific string. Also, I need to find the first line in the file with text wrapped by either [] or <>. Then I need to dump all this out to a file (I know I can do that by appending > filename.type to the end of the grep). Also, it would be helpful to find statistics, like how many of my subset of files contain any given string. I know this is a convoluted question, but I don't know how to break it up. Any help on useful grep statements would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the list of files that contains both search strings, you could say:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "grep -iq 'string1' {} && grep -iq 'string2' {} && echo {}" \;
```

To list the lines containing `string2` in the files containing `string1`, you could say:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "grep -iq 'string1' {} && grep -i 'string2' {}" \;
```